# Cannot figure out how vue-router works

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue.js project with the following router:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Overview from '@/components/Overview';
import Experiment from '@/components/ForExperiment';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: 'test',
    },
    {
      path: '/overview',
      component: Overview,
    },
    {
      path: '/overview/from/:from/to/:to',
      name: 'overview',
      component: Overview,
    },
    //... some other urls goes here.
    {
      path: '/test',
      name: 'test',
      component: Experiment,
    },
  ],
});
```

If I open `http://localhost:8080` in a browser I am redirected to `http://localhost:8080/#/test`. Why not just `http://localhost:8080/test`? Where does the '#' symbol come from?

And why if I open `http://localhost:8080/test` am I redirected to `http://localhost:8080/test#/test`?

And what is even more strange, if I open `http://localhost:8080/overview` I am redirected to `http://localhost:8080/overview#/test`, so the Overview component is not displayed.

What can cause these strange effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vue router defaults to [`hash` mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html). For your url to go to `http://localhost:8080/test` you need to go into `history` mode. This is done because by default web servers are not setup to redirect all requests to one html file. `hash` mode is used to per the docs:

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.

Change your router to this to get `history` mode. But you will need to [configure NGINX or Apache2](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) to redirect all requests to your vue code

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history', // Add this to your router
  routes: [...]
})
```

Comment: I am not sure what web server is used in the production, but in my development environment I do not have neither Nginx nor Apache, I just type 'npm run dev'.

Comment: The `history` mode will work on `npm run dev` without any additional setup. But once it does go to production based on your web server an additional setup will be required. The configuration will need to forward all traffic to index.html

Answer (score 5):

Vue router has [different modes](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode). The default mode when a browser is detected is `hash`. The current route is determined by the hash part of the url. The upside of this approach is that no serverside configuration is required. All urls point at the same resource (e.g. the route), which you can make your index.html file.

You can change this mode to `history`. The history mode uses the history api of the browser. It will only work in recent browsers, but [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=history) should not be an issue at this point. It will also require server side configuration in that you need to internally rewrite your router urls to the same file. If you would not do that, refreshing the page will show a 404 page instead of the page you want to see.

Answer (score 4):

`vue-router` default mode is hash mode, that is why you see a `#` on your URL. It uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL without reloading the page if it changes.

To get rid of the hash, we can use `vue-router` history mode. Change the `mode` like so:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

This leverages the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

If you want to use the history mode, you'll need to change your server configuration. Vue Router docs has some examples [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Comment: I am not sure what server I have. What is the server if I just type 'npm run dev' to host the website?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I wouldn't recommending to run `npm run dev` to host the website. But it's possible. There are web-pack features that change from `dev` mode to `production` mode once the files are build. There will be a lot of extra overhang in your app if you run `dev` mode in production.